Odoo 15 enterprise :reward lines not loaded in the POS when server is overloaded
Steps to reproduce the issue:
install POS coupon, sale coupon, create a product and add it to a promotion program as a specific product with a discount x% and add the promotion program in a point of sale.
for the same order created from the module Sales for that product, when I click on the button promotions it will add the discount line.
when I open the POS, where there are many users working on the module Point of sale, when opening a point of sale and choose the order, sometimes for the same order the discount line sometimes appear sometimes not even when I click on Reset Programs the discount line will not be displayed, I have to close the session and open it again sometimes.
After investigation, I think the problem is that this function when overloaded it will return an empty list: the following code is from the standard odoo 15 enterprise module pos_coupon
  _getActiveOnCurrentPromoPrograms: function () {             return this.activePromoProgramIds                 .map((program_id) => [this.pos.coupon_programs_by_id[program_id], null])                 .filter(([program]) => {                     return program.promo_applicability === 'on_current_order';                 });         },
Here is the full code
                      ` _getValidActivePrograms: async function (rewardsContainer) {
        const freeProductPrograms = [],
            fixedAmountDiscountPrograms = [],
            onSpecificPrograms = [],
            onCheapestPrograms = [],
            onOrderPrograms = [];`


        function updateProgramLists(program, coupon_id) {
            if (program.reward_type === 'product') {
                freeProductPrograms.push([program, coupon_id]);
            } else {
                if (program.discount_type === 'fixed_amount') {
                    fixedAmountDiscountPrograms.push([program, coupon_id]);
                } else if (program.discount_apply_on === 'specific_products') {
                    onSpecificPrograms.push([program, coupon_id]);
                } else if (program.discount_apply_on === 'cheapest_product') {
                    onCheapestPrograms.push([program, coupon_id]);
                } else {
                    onOrderPrograms.push([program, coupon_id]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (let [program, coupon_id] of this._getBookedPromoPrograms()) {
            // Booked coupons from on next order promo programs do not need
            // checking of rules because checks are done before generating
            // coupons.
            updateProgramLists(program, coupon_id);
        }

        for (let [program, coupon_id] of [
            ...this._getBookedCouponPrograms(),
            ...this._getActiveOnCurrentPromoPrograms(),
        ]) {
            const { successful, reason } = await this._checkProgramRules(program);
            if (successful) {
                updateProgramLists(program, coupon_id);
            } else {
                // side-effect
                const notAwarded = new Reward({ program, coupon_id, reason, awarded: false });
                rewardsContainer.add([notAwarded]);
            }
        }

        return {
            freeProductPrograms,
            fixedAmountDiscountPrograms,
            onSpecificPrograms,
            onCheapestPrograms,
            onOrderPrograms,
        };
    },

 _calculateRewards: async function () {
        const rewardsContainer = new RewardsContainer();

        if (this._getRegularOrderlines().length === 0) {
            return rewardsContainer;
        }

        const {
            freeProductPrograms,
            fixedAmountDiscountPrograms,
            onSpecificPrograms,
            onCheapestPrograms,
            onOrderPrograms,
        } = await this._getValidActivePrograms(rewardsContainer);

        const collectRewards = (validPrograms, rewardGetter) => {
            const allRewards = [];
            for (let [program, coupon_id] of validPrograms) {
                const [rewards, reason] = rewardGetter(program, coupon_id);
                if (reason) {
                    const notAwarded = new Reward({ awarded: false, reason, program, coupon_id });
                    rewardsContainer.add([notAwarded]);
                }
                allRewards.push(...rewards);
            }
            return allRewards;
        };

        // - Gather the product rewards
        const freeProducts = collectRewards(freeProductPrograms, this._getProductRewards.bind(this));

        // - Gather the fixed amount discounts
        const fixedAmountDiscounts = collectRewards(fixedAmountDiscountPrograms, this._getFixedDiscount.bind(this));

        // - Gather the specific discounts
        const specificDiscountGetter = (program, coupon_id) => {
            return this._getSpecificDiscount(program, coupon_id, freeProducts);
        };
        const specificDiscounts = collectRewards(onSpecificPrograms, specificDiscountGetter);

        // - Collect the discounts from on order and on cheapest discount programs.
        const globalDiscounts = [];
        const onOrderDiscountGetter = (program, coupon_id) => {
            return this._getOnOrderDiscountRewards(program, coupon_id, freeProducts);
        };
        globalDiscounts.push(...collectRewards(onOrderPrograms, onOrderDiscountGetter));
        globalDiscounts.push(...collectRewards(onCheapestPrograms, (program, coupon_id) => this._getOnCheapestProductDiscount(program, coupon_id, freeProducts)));

        // - Group the discounts by program id.
        const groupedGlobalDiscounts = {};
        for (let discount of globalDiscounts) {
            const key = [discount.program.id, discount.coupon_id].join(',');
            if (!(key in groupedGlobalDiscounts)) {
                groupedGlobalDiscounts[key] = [discount];
            } else {
                groupedGlobalDiscounts[key].push(discount);
            }
        }

        // - We select the group of discounts with highest total amount.
        // Note that the result is an Array that might contain more than one
        // discount lines. This is because discounts are grouped by tax.
        let currentMaxTotal = 0;
        let currentMaxKey = null;
        for (let key in groupedGlobalDiscounts) {
            const discountRewards = groupedGlobalDiscounts[key];
            const newTotal = discountRewards.reduce((sum, discReward) => sum + discReward.discountAmount, 0);
            if (newTotal > currentMaxTotal) {
                currentMaxTotal = newTotal;
                currentMaxKey = key;
            }
        }
        const theOnlyGlobalDiscount = currentMaxKey
            ? groupedGlobalDiscounts[currentMaxKey].filter((discountReward) => discountReward.discountAmount !== 0)
            : [];

        // - Get the messages for the discarded global_discounts
        if (theOnlyGlobalDiscount.length > 0) {
            const theOnlyGlobalDiscountKey = [
                theOnlyGlobalDiscount[0].program.id,
                theOnlyGlobalDiscount[0].coupon_id,
            ].join(',');
            for (let [key, discounts] of Object.entries(groupedGlobalDiscounts)) {
                if (key !== theOnlyGlobalDiscountKey) {
                    const notAwarded = new Reward({
                        program: discounts[0].program,
                        coupon_id: discounts[0].coupon_id,
                        reason: 'Not the greatest global discount.',
                        awarded: false,
                    });
                    rewardsContainer.add([notAwarded]);
                }
            }
        }

        // - Add the calculated rewards.
        rewardsContainer.add([
            ...freeProducts,
            ...fixedAmountDiscounts,
            ...specificDiscounts,
            ...theOnlyGlobalDiscount,
        ]);

        return rewardsContainer;
    },

 _getNewRewardLines: async function () {
        // Remove the reward lines before recalculation of rewards.
        this.orderlines.remove(this._getRewardLines());
        const rewardsContainer = await this._calculateRewards();
        // We set the programs that will generate coupons after validation of this order.
        // See `_postPushOrderResolve` in the `PaymentScreen`.
        await this._setProgramIdsToGenerateCoupons(rewardsContainer);
        // Create reward orderlines here based on the content of `rewardsContainer` field.
        return [this._getLinesToAdd(rewardsContainer), rewardsContainer];
    },

initialize: function () {
        _order_super.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.on(
            'update-rewards',
            () => {
                if (!this.pos.config.use_coupon_programs) return;
                dp.add(this._getNewRewardLines()).then(([newRewardLines, rewardsContainer]) => {
                    newRewardLines.forEach(line => this.add_orderline(line));
                    // We need this for the rendering of ActivePrograms component.
                    this.rewardsContainer = rewardsContainer;
                    // Send a signal that the rewardsContainer are updated.
                    this.trigger('rewards-updated');
                }).catch(() => { /* catch the reject of dp when calling `add` to avoid unhandledrejection */ });
            },
            this
        );
        this.on('reset-coupons', this.resetCoupons, this);
        this._initializePrograms();
        return this;
    },

`
you can check the file coupon.js https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/pos_coupon/static/src/js/coupon.js
is there a way to reload the active promotion programs where are not reloaded ....?
the reward lines should be loaded in the POS when I choose an order that have products that have rewards according the related promotion programs rules
